# Eclipse: An error has occurred. See the log file

Tags: android, eclipse

I can't find any answered forums that fits in my problem.

My Log file from

F:ANDROID APPLICATION\eclipse\configuration\1394593457847.log:

```
!SESSION 2014-03-12 10:59:54.740 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.I20130605-2000
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-03-12 10:59:55.239
!MESSAGE Error loading bundle datas.  Recalculating cache.
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.loadBaseData(BaseStorage.java:993)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.readBundleDatas(BaseStorage.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getInstalledBundles(BaseStorage.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getInstalledBundles(BaseAdaptor.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-03-12 10:59:55.371
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version "1717986918.1717986918.1717986918.fffffffffffffffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff7efd6cebdfffff7fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff7e7ded6fffff7efe7ded6cec6
.....(MORE "FFFFFFF")...
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
    at org.osgi.framework.Version.validate(Version.java:205)
    at org.osgi.framework.Version.<init>(Version.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.readVersion(StateReader.java:718)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.readBaseDescription(StateReader.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.readGenericDescription(StateReader.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.readBundleDescriptionLazyData(StateReader.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.fullyLoad(StateReader.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.BundleDescriptionImpl.loadLazyData(BundleDescriptionImpl.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.BundleDescriptionImpl.setLazyLoaded(BundleDescriptionImpl.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateImpl.resolveBundle(StateImpl.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateImpl.resolveBundle(StateImpl.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateImpl.removeBundle(StateImpl.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.checkSystemState(BaseStorage.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getState(BaseAdaptor.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.frameworkStart(BaseStorage.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: I see a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError; how much memory are you giving it, and how much physical memory is there?

Comment: How will I know about those memories? @nitind

Comment: F:ANDROID APPLICATION\eclipse\eclipse.ini , but it also looks like you've got a bad plug-in installed with a really strange version number.

Answer (score 0):

IF the eclipse is installed on ubuntu, maybe you can try this command:

X86_64（64）:
cp /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64

X86（32）:
cp /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86